# How to prevent users from getting at the source files for Excel Web Services

Tags: security, excel

I have a request to put a large Excel dataset on a MOSS 2007 sharepoint page.
The XLSX is about 13 MB in values alone - about 50,000 rows. It's updated weekly, usually in batch form (i.e. some hundreds of records changed).

I am hosting it through Excel Web Services.

What's the best way to keep my users from being able to download the entire file?  I know I can restrict their view of it, but how do I stop them from accessing the source library?

Answer (score 1):

You can't really.  Users have to have read access to the file to be able to see the Excel Services web part, and by giving that right, you open the door for them to download the file.  Since they would only have read permisions, they wouldn't be able to upload any changes they would make locally.

Answer (score 0):

I just succesfully provided a view to an excel spreadsheet in a "Excel Web Access" web part.  If you hide the toolbar and the chrome, the user has no idea where the source is.  MAYBE if they could sniff packets or look at the source HTML... but if you have someone going to that lengths to find your source, you probably don't want to share it with them.

edit- I also used CSS in a CEWP to hide the top nav and quick launch.